# Stock grant and taxes

Tags: united-states, stocks, income-tax, irs

As a retention incentive, I was granted stock (about $60,000) in my employers privately owned company.

The stock grant went through payroll in December and had FICA taken out but no income tax. I anticipate a huge tax bill when I file ($20,000+).

Is the IRS going to clobber me for this? Will I have penalties for not paying quarterly taxes or be forced to pay quarterly taxes this year even though this was a one-time thing? Should I do anything now or handle it all when I file?